# GridBagLayout doing strange things when trying to add message JLabel below a grid of squares

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel, gridbaglayout

I am trying to display a `JLabel` of a message below a grid of displayed squares (each square is a `JLabel`). When I don't try to add the message to the `JPanel`, the **4x4** grid of squares displays just fine. However, when I try and add the message `JLabel` below or above the grid, what happens is that the Grid of squares becomes split in two (after the first column of squares), such that one column of squares displays on the left, then there is a gap, and then the other three columns of squares are displayed. The message displays beneath. Why does adding this message cause the grid of squares to split like this? I have put my code below. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
public void displayGrid(JButton button) {

    JLabel instructionsLabel = new JLabel ("Select the locations of the four objects that you saw previously. Be careful - when you select one box, you can't take it back.");

    try {
        squareImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("stimulus(0).gif"));  

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        c.gridx = i % 4;
        c.gridy = i / 4;
        squareLabels[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(squareImage));
        panel.add(squareLabels[i], c);
        squareLabels[i].addMouseListener(this);
    }

    panel.validate();

    c.gridy += 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    panel.add(instructionsLabel, c);
    panel.validate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your `instructionsLabel` to the first column of the fifth row, after the 4*4 matrix of `JLabel`s.

The problem is because your `instructionsLabel` has a longer length than your `squareLabels[i]`, so the default behavior of `GridBagLayout` would stretch the first column to fit the `instructionsLabel`.

You need to set the `gridWidth` for the your `GridBagConstraints` object `c` before adding the `instructionsLabel` :

```
c.gridy += 1;
c.gridx = 0;
constraint.gridwidth = 4;
panel.add(instructionsLabel, c);
```

By setting `constraint.gridwidth = 4;` you are telling the layout manager to place the `instructionsLabel` in more than one column. (Here I set exaclty 4 columns.)

Adding some `LineBorder` to your `JLabel`s would help you to understand the behavior of `GridBagLayout` and its `Constraints` better.

**[UPDATE]**
You can use `BorderLayout` as the main layout, and then add the `JPanel` with your `JLabel`s and other components to the center of `BorderLayout`. Then in that `JPanel` use the `GridBagLayout`. See this example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestGridBagLAyout extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -392403850862179703L;
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 200;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200;

    public TestGridBagLAyout() {
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        //
        setForeground(Color.RED);
        //
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(initCenterPanel());
    }

    private JPanel initCenterPanel() {
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(gridBagLayout);
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //
        GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 0d, 0d, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        //
        JLabel[] squareLabels = new JLabel[16];
        for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            constraint.gridx = i % 4;
            constraint.gridy = i / 4;
            squareLabels[i] = new JLabel("Test");
            centerPanel.add(squareLabels[i], constraint);
        }
        //
        JLabel instructionsLabel = new JLabel("This is long instruction!");
        constraint.gridy += 1;
        constraint.gridx = 0;
        constraint.gridwidth = 4;
        centerPanel.add(instructionsLabel, constraint);
        //
        return centerPanel;
    }
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I do not understand what you are doing here.

Comment: Thanks. I understand why you suggested that now.  I changed the value of gridwidth, and the grid displays 4x4. However, the grid is not displaying in the centre of the JPanel (it is to the left of centre). Do you know why this might be the case and how to move it into the centre of the JPanel?

Comment: See the update for centering the JLabels. If this answer helps you can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a separate GridBagConstraints object - you can't reuse the same instance as you are doing above.

Comment: Do you mean GridBagConstraints? I thought using the same instance was the whole idea. If you are using two different GridBagConstraints then you would not be able to make it so that they didn't interfere with each other.

Comment: There is no problem with the re-use of `GridBagConstraints` :  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: Okay, I'm fairly sure I have had problems in the past with using the same GridBagConstraints object - but I'm willing to accept that I'm wrong.  You have very clear IO and Swing model manipulation on the same thread in your code - consider using the SwingWorker to manage the IO task.  Also, you have 'c.gridy = i / 4;' in there which looks like a bug to me - is this by design?

Comment: That is not a bug. It works fine because the grid displays adequately when I don't put the message label beneath. I'm confused because whenever I have ever seen anyone else on this site using the GridBagLayout layout manager to organise components in a JFrame, they always only use one instance of GridBagConstraints.

Comment: I use a separate GridBagConstraints for each Swing component because it's easier for readers of my code to understand what I'm doing.  I think separate GridBagConstraints was required in Java 1.4, but not since then.